# How can I configure Alt+Tab and the launcher to only show apps in the current workspace?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, unity, workspaces

I don't like that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I see all open apps in all workspaces. How can I see in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu and in the launcher  only the programs that I am using in that particular workspace? I feel there's no point of using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the launcher if you have opened lots of programs in different workspaces. Hope you understand, please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with the default Unity switcher, but you could use one of the other switchers compiz offers: Shift Switcher, Ring Switcher, Application Switcher, Static Application Switcher. They are found under "Window Manager" in ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager). You can disable the Alt+Tab binding for the switcher in the "Unity Plugin" in ccsm, and enable one of these switchers and configure their bindings as you wish.