# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME) workspace prohibit alt-tab to windows on other workspaces

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces, application-switcher

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 running GNOME desktop environment

I have two workspaces, one and two, with following windows

- Work space 1: shell 1, chrome 1
- Work space 2: shell 2, chrome 2

I want: when I'm in a particular workspace, I can only alt-tab to windows that were opened in that workspace (other windows that were not opened in that workspace should not show up).

I'm aware of some of these related questions:

1. [this one seems like what I am asking here, but the answer was for Unity, not GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73821/how-can-i-configure-alttab-and-the-launcher-to-only-show-apps-in-the-current-wo)
2. [The question + answer only make it so that the dock doesn't **show** windows from other workspaces, I can still alt-tab with it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992558/how-can-i-configure-the-ubuntu-dock-to-show-windows-only-from-the-current-worksp)

Comment: Yes, I just followed your link, it is a duplicate, just different ubuntu version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To ensure that the default task switcher of Gnome Shell (Ubuntu 17.10 and higher) only shows applications of the current workspace, change a setting using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
```

You can also change this setting with dconf-editor, a graphical tool that allows inspecting and changing a range of settings of any application that uses the gsettings framework.

To reset to the default setting:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate Tab** extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/

+

**Workspace Isolated Dash** extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/ (Isn't work by default with **Dash to panel**!) or use **Dash to panel** https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ Settings -> Behavior -> Isolate Workspaces

Comment: I noticed that you were the first to answer my question, thanks for fast response. I haven't tried your solution though, because I don't really want to install extensions. I am going to mark the other solution as it solves my problem in the way that I prefer.